# R - dbplyr - `lang_name()` is deprecated

Tags: r, dbplyr

I just updated dblyr and since that moment I started to saw warnings

> Warning messages: 1: `lang_name()` is deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0.
>   Please use `call_name()` instead. This warning is displayed once per
>   session.  2: `lang()` is deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0. Please use
>   `call2()` instead. This warning is displayed once per session.

I have no clue what sould I do since my code looks like this

```
df <- tbl(conn, in_schema("schema", "table")) %>%
filter(status!= "CLOSED" | is.na(status)) %>%
      group_by(customer_id) %>%
      filter(created == min(created, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(
        contract_number,
        customer_id,
        approved_date = created 
      ) %>%
      collect()
```

There is no call_name() or lang_name() in my code. Do you guys know whats wrong? I know that my code works even with this warnings, but I don't want to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned there is nothing wrong and your code works fine as this is a warning. The window function in `dbplyr` still uses the `lang_name()` function call. The window function is called within your `filter( ... == min(...))` statements. There is already an issue on Github open for this [link](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/328).

If you do not want to see the warning you can suppress it like this:

```
suppressWarnings(df <- tbl(conn, in_schema("schema", "table")) %>%
filter(status!= "CLOSED" | is.na(status)) %>%
      group_by(customer_id) %>%
      filter(created == min(created, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(
        contract_number,
        customer_id,
        approved_date = created 
      ) %>%
      collect())
```

Comment: Wonder when they'll fix it?